# Effect on roots of function on taking the derivative of the function

Tags: functions, roots

Suppose there is a function $$f(x)=(x-1)^{15}(x-2)^{20}(x-3)^{25}(x-4)^{30}$$
As we take the derivatives of the function, what will happen to the number of **real roots** and the number of **distinct real roots**? Can we explain it with the help of IMVT or Rolle's theorem?

Comment: I recommend that you look at a small case first. Then it build it up. For instance, try it with say $f(x) = (x - 1)^2 (x - 2)^2$.

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/94901/8173) based on Rolle's theorem should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x-r)^n|P(x)$, then $(x-r)^{n-1}|P'(x)$. Then using Rolle's should give you a pretty good idea.